# Inkscape - Object to Path on a word creates a single path instead of a path per letter

Tags: inkscape

**Goal**: When running `Object to Path` on a word, I'd like each letter to have its own path.

All the tutorials I saw behave exactly like the above description, but when I try to run this action I get a single path for the whole word.

Is this something I should configure in Preferences?

- MacOS 14.2.1
- Inkscape 1.3.2

Edit: I found that I can use `Path > Break Apart` in order to have the letters separated. Still wondering if this can be achieved immediately when using the `object to path` function.

Comment: You can't do that in one step. Not possible AFAIK. Do this instead: Path > Object to Path, then Path > Split Path.